# плавный переход по якорным ссылкам и выравнивание по центру

Tags: javascript, css

у меня на странице есть переход по якорям, реализован так:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top;
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#yak1">Ссылка на якорь 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yak2">Ссылка на якорь 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yak3">Ссылка на якорь 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yak4">Ссылка на якорь 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Все работает, но моя страница очень широкая (3000 px) . Как сделать так чтобы например переход был не только вниз, но и влево и вправо, или чтобы переход выравнивался по центру элемента?

Вообщем был дополнительный вопрос, но модератор его удалил, типо нельзя писать в ответах вопрос. Скрипт который в первом ответе у меня работает так: Сначало переходит резко влево а потом уже плавно вниз. По диагонале не как не хочет идти. Из за чего это может быть?

Answer (score 2):

Короче как-то так :D
Если будет не понятно, пишите, распишу подробнее)

```js
$('a').on('click',function(){
  var a = $(this).attr('href'),
      winWidth = $(window).width(),
      winHeight = $(window).height(),
      blockWidth = $(a).width(),
      blockHeight = $(a).height(),
      posBlock = $(a).offset();

      $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: (posBlock.top - ((winHeight/2) - (blockWidth/2))),
        scrollLeft: (posBlock.left - ((winWidth/2) - (blockHeight/2)))
      }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.big_block {
  width: 4000px;
  height: 4000px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
}

.small_block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.small_block[data-num="1"] {
  top: calc(500px - 50px);
  left: calc(500px - 50px);
}

.small_block[data-num="2"] {
  top: calc(1000px - 50px);
  left: calc(1000px - 50px);
}

.small_block[data-num="3"] {
  top: calc(1500px - 50px);
  left: calc(1500px - 50px);
}

.small_block[data-num="4"] {
  top: calc(2000px - 50px);
  left: calc(2000px - 50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#yak1">Go small block 1</a>
<a href="#yak2">Go small block 2</a>
<a href="#yak3">Go small block 3</a>
<a href="#yak4">Go small block 4</a>

<div class="big_block">
  <div id="yak1" class="small_block" data-num="1"></div>
  <div id="yak2" class="small_block" data-num="2"></div>
  <div id="yak3" class="small_block" data-num="3"></div>
  <div id="yak4" class="small_block" data-num="4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуй переделаю под то, как у Вас в примере. **UPD** всё, переделал.

Comment: . Сделал все как у вас, но почему то так не работает. Тоесть он сначала перемещается резко влево, а потом уже идет плавно вниз. Если убрать другие мои блоки, то структура такая:

Comment: Понятия не имею как тут отвечать на ответ, но вообщем еще один вопрос к вам сверху

Comment: @АлексейЩетинин, тут, в примере так же работает? Если да, то как-то "устанавливаете" не правильно.

Comment: нет там проблема была вдругом. Там к большому модулю у меня прикручен скрипт горизонтального скролинго при наведение на боковые края. Пришлось разделить скрипт так: 

      $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: (posBlock.top - ((winHeight/2) - (blockWidth/2)))
      }, 1500);
   $('div').animate({
        scrollLeft: (posBlock.left - ((winWidth/2) - (blockHeight/2)))
      }, 1500);
   window.stop();
});

Comment: Но теперь если с левой части экрана оно переходит нормально до блока, то с правой, оно переезжает его влево и блок остается за видимой облостью в правой части